# Multipart without RequestBody throws 415

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, multipart

I have created simple rest method to upload and add file via multipart in Spring Boot. 
I don't have any `@RequestBody` so I'm quite astonished why the browser throws `415 -> "Unsupported Media Type" Content type 'null' not supported`
The controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/file")
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private FileServiceImpl fileService;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('CLIENT')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=multipart/*", produces = "application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public File uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        Principal name = httpRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        if (name.getName() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Brak sesji");
        }
        User userByLogin = userRepository.findUserByLogin(name.getName());
        File f = null;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                f = new File(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getBytes(), file.getName(), file.getContentType(), new Date(), userByLogin);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (f != null) {
            fileService.uploadFile(f);
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

At the frontend looks like

```
<div>
<label>Dodaj załącznik</label>
<input type="file" files-model="file" >
<button ng-click="addFile()">Dodaj</button>
</div>

 $scope.addFile = function () {
          FileService.save($scope.file);
 }
```

The fail looks like:

```
{"timestamp":1491988354597,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'null' not supported","path":"/api/file"}
```

Comment: Try to remove consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE. You are uploading file but your mapping expects JSON. Try to use multipart/form-data as consumes

Comment: @StanislavL the same bug still

Answer (score 0):

you have to append your file in formData.

```
<div>
<label></label>
<input type="file" files-model="file" id="file" >
<button ng-click="addFile()">Dodaj</button>
</div>

$scope.addFile = function () {
      var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
      FileService.save(formData);
 };
```

In FileService service you have to set headers: {Content-Type:undefined}

this should work!

Comment: Added
`angular.module('sbAdminApp').factory('FileService', function($resource) {

    var service = $resource('api/file', {
        id : '@id'
    }, {
        post: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'content-Type' :undefined}
        }

    });

    return service;
});` 
and still the same fail

Comment: In your service you have called service method "FileService.save" but it should be "FileService.post" becasue you have "post" method in your service.

Comment: But $resource share a 'save' method to save object, so how to add to that method headers instead of creating cimpletly new method which will do pretty the same?

Comment: but you have to you use the method  which you have created in service. $resource provide "$save" which contains no headers setting i think.

Comment: Ok, redefined a new method but now has `
"Required request part 'uploadedFile' is not present"` -> but in my java controller method I have `@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFile` and in HTML also that name `<input type="file" files-model="file" id="file" name="uploadedFile">`

Comment: if your api endpoint is like "api/file/:$id" then you have to do some change in your front-end controller.
FileService.save({id:"id  here ", data:formData});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141539/discussion-between-bielas-and-ravi-kumar).